# CSS not applied. chrome dev tool

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to know why my CSS not applied. 
and What does it mean when CSS part has been dimmed in chrome dev tool.

[image]

Comment: the element don't have `card` class

Comment: dimmed means not an inheritable property. `.card` is an upper parent which those styles are applied to but not the currently selected element which is `.bespoke...`

Comment: then how can I apply `.card` setting to `.bespoke_input_group`  ? @Zohir

Comment: Add the class `.card` to it